# how to make an outer join with the calling of other procedure

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, informix

I have a stored procedure :

> procedure qr_get_dep_boss(...,...)

takes two params(`year`, `main_code`) and returning one record the `boss_num` and his name .

I want to create another procedure and make a loop on the previous procedure calling , making an `outer join` with the result of another query

```
SELECT 
  year,
  main_code,
  name,
  CASE 
    WHEN father_code in(-1)  THEN NULL
    ELSE father_code 
  END AS father_code,main_code || '_' || year AS main_id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM sm_r_build 
   WHERE father_code = sc.main_code 
     AND year = (SELECT MAX(year)
                 FROM st_quit_info)) childcount,
   main_code||'_'|| father_code AS serial 
FROM sm_r_build sc 
WHERE year=(SELECT MAX(year)FROM st_quit_info)
```

So I want the result:

```
year,main_code,name,father_code,main_id,childcount,serial,boss_num,boss_name
```

---

I try this :

```
create procedure new_get_alldepwithboss()
returning int as year , int as main_code ,nvarchar(100) as name,int as father_code,nvarchar(255) as main_id,int as childcount,int as ll_boss_num,nvarchar(100) as ll_boss_name 

define ll_year int;
define ll_main_code int;
define ll_name nvarchar(100);
define ll_father_code int;
define ll_main_id nvarchar(255) ;
define ll_childcount int;
define ll_boss_num int;
define ll_boss_name nvarchar(100);

foreach 
SELECT year,main_code,name,CASE WHEN father_code in(-1)  THEN NULL ELSE father_code END AS father_code,main_code || '_' || year AS main_id, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM sm_r_build 
WHERE father_code=sc.main_code AND year= (SELECT MAX(year)
FROM st_quit_info)) childcount ,a.emp_num,a.emp_name
INTO ll_year ,ll_main_code,ll_name  ,ll_father_code ,ll_main_id ,ll_childcount ,ll_boss_num,ll_boss_name
FROM sm_r_build  sc , TABLE(FUNCTION qr_get_dep_boss(ll_main_code, ll_year))AS a(emp_num,emp_name)  
WHERE year=(SELECT MAX(year)FROM st_quit_info)


return ll_year , ll_main_code, ll_name,ll_father_code,ll_main_id, ll_childcount ,  ll_boss_num,ll_boss_name with resume;

end foreach

end procedure
```

but in vain !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of SQL server I would recommend using rather function than store procedure. Header of function should look:

```
CREATE FUNCTION qr_get_dep_boss( @year DATE, @main_code INT)
RETURN @t TABLE ( boss_num INT, boss_name VARCHAR(50))
AS
... ( here boss_num and boss_name  should be set )
```

In your main query you can use this function by:

```
SELECT year, main_code, ... , t.bos_num , t.boss_name 
FROM ...
CROSS APPLY
qr_get_dep_boss(year, main_code) t
```

But I am not sure if it is possible in Informix, in case not you can always define two functions that returns single value. GL!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you don't need the second procedure.

What you need to do is use the `RETURN xxx WITH RESUME` into the procedure qr_get_dep_boss()

A example copied from the [manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0063.htm) .

```
CREATE FUNCTION series (limit INT, backwards INT) RETURNING INT;
   DEFINE i INT;
   FOR i IN (1 TO limit)
      RETURN i WITH RESUME;
   END FOR;
   IF backwards = 0 THEN
      RETURN;
   END IF;
   FOR i IN (limit TO 1 STEP -1)
      RETURN i WITH RESUME;
   END FOR;
END FUNCTION; -- series
```